# Inefficient Curve Fitting Using Scipy Curve Fit

Tags: numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I´m working on a model, using [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to find the parameters that better fit the data. In order to investigate if the function is working properply, I started fitting random inputs with added noise as the documentation suggests.

The functions:

```
def mom(x, alpha=.5, theta=1, k=1, s=.5, beta=1):
    # Weight Function
    w_ = np.array([alpha ** ((l - theta) ** 2) for l in range(13)])
    # Adstock Function
    X_ = np.array([(sum(w_ * np.array([x[i - l]
                                       if ((i - l) >= 0)
                                       else 0
                                       for l in range(13)]
                                      )
                        )
                    ) / sum(w_)
                   for i in range(len(x))
                   ]
                  )
    return np.array([beta-(((k**s)*beta)/((x**s)+(k**s))) for x in X_])
```

As you can see, the function is non-linear and their partial derivatives rather complex. The function implemented here is the [Hill Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) combined with the [Adstock Function](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/pt-BR//pubs/archive/46001.pdf) (Equation 3):

Then I iteratively run [*curve_fit*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and measure the distribution of the fitted params to their true value with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse, meanabs, maxabs

def get_default_args(func):
    import inspect
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    return {
        k: v.default
        for k, v in signature.parameters.items()
        if v.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty
    }


true_params = get_default_args(mom)

model_res = [] 
for i in range(100):
    X = np.random.random_sample((36,))

    ydata = mom(X)
    y_noise = 0.02 * np.random.normal(size=X.size)
    Y = ydata + y_noise

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(mom, X, Y,
                           method='trf',
                           bounds=([0, 0, 0, 0, -2], [1, 12, 5, 5, 2]),
                           maxfev=10000)

    acc = rmse(ydata, mom(X, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4]))
    mae = meanabs(ydata, mom(X, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4]))
    maxe = maxabs(ydata, mom(X, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4]))

    model_res.append({'alpha': popt[0],
                      'theta': popt[1],
                      'k': popt[2],
                      's': popt[3],
                      'beta': popt[4],
                      'rmse': acc,
                      'mae': mae,
                      'max_error': maxe})

    # appending covariance matrix
    cov.append(pcov)

    print("{0} of 100".format(i), end='\r', flush=True)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(model_res)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30)) 
axs = []

for i in range(1, 9):
    axs.append(fig.add_subplot(4, 2, i))

for col, ax in zip(df.select_dtypes(include="float64").columns, axs):        
    if col in true_params.keys():
        ax.axvline(true_params[col], linewidth=4, color='r')
        ax.legend(labels=["True {0}".format(col)], loc='upper right')
    else:
        ax.axvline(df[col].mean(), linewidth=4, color='r')
        ax.axvline(df[col].median(), linewidth=4, color='g')
        ax.legend(labels=["Mean", "Median"], loc='upper right')

    sns.distplot(a=df[col], ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

You can notice that I´m using a constrained approach because the function is not differentiable and continuous throughout the domain

This code generally produce these outputs:
[image]

As you can see, most of the variable are well behaved and acumulate around the true value more or less normally distributed. That´s not the case of ***Beta*** and ***K***. There´s any "simple enough" explanation for the difficulty of [*curve_fit*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) in fitting these specific parameters? Is there anyway I could improve the code performance? There are better approaches to fit these parameters than [*curve_fit*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)?

**WHAT A I WANT (OR EXPECTED OUTPUT) :** *All the fitted params to have a normal (or quasi-normal) distribution with the mean close to the true value and an standard deviation as small as  possible.*

**P.S:** *Beta and K must me > 0 but theoretically you could loose the upper bounds. However, if you do so, [*curve_fit*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) is unable to fit and diverge. Also no idea why...*

**EDIT**: Following [Christian´s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588210/christian-k) suggestion, I also kept the covariance matrix´s and that´s how they look like:

Average Values:

[image: Average Covariance Matrix]

Median Values:

[image: Median Covariance Matrix]

Comment: To me the fits don't look that bad, given the fact that the discretization for alpha and K is lower (more coarse). The fit for beta looks about as good as the other ones. Could you be more clear on what you are asking?

Comment: Find these values are just a intermediate step for my actual problem which envolves optmize the function which the params I´m trying to find in this question. So my objective function take the mean and std of the fitted params as an input...

In this case.. having to modes to choose is bad

I´m editing the question to be more specific and clear

Comment: * I ment **two modes** in the case of beta and k, with bimodal distribution outputs

Comment: K and beta are probably not responsible for the normal shape in your fit function, right?

Comment: Maybe there is some correlation between K and beta so that they may compensate each other. What does the covariance matrix look like?

Comment: Are you sure about the implementation of `mom`? The result depends on whether the input array is equidistant.

Comment: @ChristianK. I´ve edited the question to provide the covariance matrix.